# How to flag a value in a series in highcharts, and follow it, even if the position in the series change?

Tags: highcharts

Long story short; I have a series of numbers and dates, in a CSV file

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
Jun 21 10:20, Jun 21 11:00, Jun 21 11:12,Jun 21 11:55,Jun 21 2:30,Jun 21 4:22
```

This file is updated every few hours, with new values, so more are added and I display the last 10.

Is there a way to mark in high chart a specific value, say the one at 11:00, and continue to follow it even when the value move (for example from position 2 to position 1)?

I track the value adding its value and timestamp to the bottom of the file:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
Jun 21 10:20, Jun 21 11:00, Jun 21 11:12,Jun 21 11:55,Jun 21 2:30,Jun 21 4:22
2,Jun 21 11:00
```

I have tried various approach; but I can't figure out how can I mark that value and follow it, until it is out of the range

What would be the logic to achieve this? in bash I would add a flag, but I am not sure how would you do that in highCharts.

Comment: How do you know which of points should be marked?

Comment: I have in the file the value and the timestamp of the point. If I can find a way to mark a value. ideally I could look in the Highcharts code for that mark, and every time that the mark is preset, mark the point. So I don't have to parse the whole chart to see if that value is there, and if I have on a chart multiple points that I need to display, I can do so to.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't answer my question. How do you know **which** of points should be marked? If you have such information, then while parsing CSV data to points, add new point in flag series for a Highstock ([demo](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/flags-general)).

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I hav a function that does the comparison of the value on the y axis, and then compare the timestamp, in case there are 2 values that are the same on the chart. Once found, it return me the point that has that value, as integer (so if I display 10 points, it will return me 4, to say the 4th point on the chart). Can I add the flag also if I use Highcharts and not high stocks?

Comment: Then if you know which point should be changed use `chart.series[0].data[index_to_mark].update({ .. });` to update that specific point. To 'flag' this point, you can use first option provided by jlbriggs. To use Flags series, you need Highstock. In Highcharts use scatter series instead (second option provided by jlbriggs).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the point that you want to mark at the time of creating the chart, you can do a couple of different things.

1) You can add additional formatting information to the data point, ie:

```
data:[8,9,8,{y:7,marker:{enabled:true,fillColor:'red'}},4,5,6,3,2,1]
```

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3qtZr/13/

2) you can add a separate scatter series with just that point, providing the x,y values

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3qtZr/15/